# HTML + jquery sometimes image not display completely

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on cordova project using jquery mobile for UI.

I need to display user picture grid.Images are being downloaded in syc. way (using callbacks) and displaying image after download successfully.

Sometimes images do no display properly.

After download succcess I use the following code :-

```
 image.src = Imageurl;
image.onload = function () {

    $(divID).empty().append(image);
    $(divID).find("img").attr("src",Imageurl);
};
```

also tried

```
  $(divID).find("img").attr("src",Imageurl);
```

and 
tried setting background image using css but no luck. Any suggestion.[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can preload the image. After it has finished loading, the page displays a button that allows you to use the preloaded image in an image tag, using only the image filename

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaykani/t1dorzm2/)

```
var my_img2 = new Image();

// notify the user that the image has been preloaded, and reveal the
// button to use the preloaded image
function notify()
{
    document.getElementById('preloadbut2').style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('after_preload').style.display = 'block';
}

function preload()
{
    my_img2.onload = notify;

    my_img2.src = 'someimage.jpg';
}

// using only the file name, we can take advantage of the preloaded image
function use_preloaded_image()
{
    document.getElementById('saturnplaceholder').src = 'someimage.jpg';
}
</script>
<input type="button" 
    id="preloadbutton2" 
    value="Preload Image" 
    onclick="preload();this.value='Loading. Please wait...'" />

<div id="after_preload" style="display: none">
<input type="button" value="Use Preloaded Image"
onclick="use_preloaded_image()" /><br />
<img src="blank.jpg" id="saturnplaceholder" width="500" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an update of the component:

```
$('#your_selector').trigger('updatelayout');
```

See the docs: https://api.jquerymobile.com/updatelayout/